# Malloc of pointers in structs + pointer arithmetic + free() + linkedList

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, malloc

I'm trying to implement a linked-list data structure which each node has a identifier key, some data of variable length (malloc), and a pointer to the next node. Now I want to have 3 functions which respectively: sets a new node to the front of the list, prints the values of a given node using identifier key, and deletes a given node.

The struct I have for the node is as follows:

```
struct node {
 char key[5];
 int* data;
 node* next;
};
struct node* headNode = NULL;
```

I have questions regarding each of functions. I will list the function codes I have and ask questions regarding that specific function below:

The code for my set function:

```
void command_set (char key[], int val[], int numOfVal){
 struct node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 strcpy(temp->key, key);
 temp->data = (int*)malloc(numOfVal*sizeof(int));
 *(temp->data) = *(val);
 temp->next = entry_head;
 entry_head = temp;
 return;
}
```

Now I have one question regarding this function:

1) Is my method of storing the data valid? i.e. "temp->data = (int*)malloc(numOfValues*sizeof(int));" + "*(temp->data) = *(val);". What I'm trying to do is dynamically allocate some memory, then store the given values as my node's data in that memory.

---

The code for my print function:

```
void printNode (char key[], int numOfVal){
 int i;
 struct node *currentNode = headNode;

 while(currentNode->next!=NULL){
     if(!strcmp(currentNode->key,key) ){
        for(i=0; i<numOfVal; i++){
            printf("%d ",*((currentNode->data)+i));
        }
        return;
    }
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
}
```

I have a one question regarding this function:

2) The data of a node is a list of integers, so does my way of printing out each integer actually work? i.e. "*((currentNode->data)+i)". What I'm trying to do is by using pointer arithmetic I print all the ints stored under data.

---

The code for my delete function:

```
void deleteNode (char key[]){
 struct node *currentNode = headNode;
 struct node *prevNode = headNode;
 while(currentNode->next!=NULL){
    if(!strcmp(currentNode->key,key) ){
            prevNode->next = currentNode->next;
            free(currentNode->data);
            free(currentNode->next);
            free(currentNode);
            return;
    }

    prevNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode->next;
 }
```

I have two questions regarding this function:

3) Am I "deleting" the nodes properly? By using free(). Is this the way to do it?

4) Is this how you link up nodes after deletion? By setting the next pointer to another node.

Please assume that malloc will not return NULL for simplicity. Also note that I have simplified my actual code, else there is way too much to post, so there might be slight errors. You may also assum that the while loops will always work (i.e. there will not be a case where (currentNode->next==NULL). The main point of this post are my questions regarding whether the method of doing something is correct.

An example of the program would be:

-set ex1 2 3 4 5

-get ex1

2 3 4 5

-set ab 32 112

-get ab

32 112

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `prevNode->next = currentNode->next;` followed by  `free(currentNode->next);` is fishy. That means that now `prevNode->next` points to freed (that is invalid) memory. There may be more issues though.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Hmmm, but wouldn't you want that to happen? Since that node is essentially none-existent now, so shouldn't all the members and itself be freed? So my thought process is, I first link the previous node to the next node, now that the link has been formed, I delete everything associated with the node to be deleted. Or should I just only free the data, and leave the old links there? Not too sure if I did it right tbh.

Comment: once memory is freed with the `free` function, it's invalid. Definitly. I think you should start by implementing a simple linked list first, there are tons of code and tutorials.

Comment: `*(temp->data) = *(val);` is fishy too, what is this supposed to do? You probably need to loop through the `val` array.

Comment: And your pointer arthmetic is not necessary: `*((currentNode->data)+i))` is complicated, you can write simply `currentNode->data[i]`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz For the line of code: '*(temp->data) = *(val);' I'm trying to assign the whole array as the data of that particular node. I thought about loops before, but it would be in the form of something like 'temp->data = data[i]', but wouldn't temp->data just take the value of the very last loop? I'm very new to C, sorry about all these questions..

Comment: @MichaelWalz As for the "currentNode->data[i]", why is data treated as an array? Isn't it an int pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strcpy(temp->key, key);
```

For the the purpose of your program, this is probably ok, but you should use strncpy(temp->key,key,5) to be safe. Or at least check the length of key to make sure it fits.

```
*(temp->data) = *(val);
```

This only sets the first index in the array. You should use memcpy here.

```
memcpy (temp->data,val, sizeof (int) * numOfVal);
```

Your print function prints the first element that doesn't match. Did you mean to do the opposite?

Your delete function does the thing. It finds the first node that doesn't match.

You also don't want to free currentNode->next;

Comment: Perfect! The memcpy was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realise that *(temp->data) = *(val); is only copying the first index and not the whole array.